# Vue if to show or hide steps based on step variable

Tags: vue.js

Currently both steps are hidden even though the step is 1. what I am doing wrong here.When step is one it should show the form and when step is 2 it show the

it show error message Property or method "step" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Is this anything to do with browser I am using Microsoft edge

```
    <div class="container" id="app">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3" v-if="step == 1">
            <h1>Enter an Address to get weather </h1>
            </hr>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="location" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a Zipcode and Address">
                <button  class="btn btn-primary" >Get Weather</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3" v-if="step == 2">
            <h1>Formatted Address</h1>
            </hr>
            <p>
                Weather Summmarys
            </p>
            </hr>
            <ul>
                <li>Current Temp:Temp</li>
                <li>Feels Like: Temp</li>
                <li>Wind Speed: speed</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        step: 1
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your code worked fine but may you need to use `v-else` or `v-else-if` :

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        step: 2
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

 <div class="container" id="app">
 <button @click="step = step == 1 ? 2 : 1">Change step</button>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3" v-if="step == 1">
            <h1>Enter an Address to get weather </h1>
            </hr>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="location" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a Zipcode and Address">
                <button  class="btn btn-primary" >Get Weather</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3" v-else-if="step == 2">
            <h1>Formatted Address</h1>
            </hr>
            <p>
                Weather Summmarys
            </p>
            </hr>
            <ul>
                <li>Current Temp:Temp</li>
                <li>Feels Like: Temp</li>
                <li>Wind Speed: speed</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: So as I told your codes work fine too (see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/u2n4obtw/)). maybe you should search for problem out of this part of code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe v-if="step **===** 1" or v-if="step **===** 2"